# How can i add fields to TfrxDBDataset

Tags: delphi

```
if Length(idStrArray)>0 then
begin
with DataModule4.ADQueryTemp do
  begin
    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('SELECT id, pato, ftest, res FROM tbl ');
    SQL.Add('WHERE id IN ('+idStrArray+')');
    Open;
    (rprMasterDataFish as Tfrxmasterdata).DataSet := frxDst_Multi;
    (rprMasterDataFish as Tfrxmasterdata).DataSetName := 'Multi';

  end;
end;
```

Hello,

I have TfrxDBDataset component. I can add fields from table like above. But i also want to add fields and values manually at runtime.

I have text file like this :

> id note
>
> 1   sample
>
> 2   sample

I want to read this text file and insert note to frxDst_Multi. Is this possible ?

I dont want to create a new column as note in tbl. Because, i have too many mysql server.

Thanks in advice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add fields to a dataset while it is open, so you have to do it before
it is opened, either in code or using the TDataSet fields editor.  If you are 
doing it in code, you can add the field in the dataset's `BeforeOpen`
event.

The next problem is that is you don't want to field to be bound to the table the
dataset accesses, you need to add it as a calculated field and set its value
in the dataset's`OnCalcFields' event - see example below.

Ideally, the added field would be a TMemoField, but unfortunately a TMemoField
can't be a calculated field (`FieldKind` = `ftMemo`).  So probably the best thing you can do is to make it a String field, but then you will need to
give it a fixed maximum size and truncate the field's value at that size when you calculate its value.

Btw, I don't know whether your `TfrxDBDataset` supports the `fkInternalCalc` fieldkind, but if it does, then you could try adding the note field as a TMemoField instead of a TStringField one.

The one thing I haven't been able to do is to load the field's value from
an external file because you haven't said in your q how to determine the
name of the file which is to be read.

Obviously, the `IsNull` check in the `frxDst_MultiCalcFields` event is to avoid the overhead of reloading the file if its contents have already been read.

```
  const
    NoteFieldSize = 4096;

  procedure TForm1.AddNoteField;
  var
    NoteField : TField;
  begin
    if frxDst_Multi.FindField('Note') = Nil then begin
      NoteField := TStringField.Create(frxDst_Multi);
      NoteField.FieldName := 'Note';
      NoteField.Size := NoteFieldSize;
      NoteField.FieldKind := fkCalculated;
      NoteField.DataSet := frxDst_Multi;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    frxDst_Multi.Open;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.frxDst_MultiCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
  var
    S : String;
  begin
    if DataSet.FieldByName('Note').IsNull then begin
      S := 'a note'; //  replace by code to set the field value
      DataSet.FieldByName('Note').AsString := Copy(S, 1, NoteFieldSize);
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.frxDst_MultiBeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
  begin
    AddNoteField;
  end;
```

Comment: Hello @MartynA it deletes other fields. Only Note field seems. Any idea?

Comment: Are your other other fields persistent ones (created in the IDE) or do you just leave it to the dataset to create them when it opens?

Comment: if i dont use AddNoteField method, my dataset has id, pato, ftest and res (table columns). But if i use AddNoteField method, my dataset has only Note. frxDst_Multi uses AdQueryTmp as a DataSource so i changed frxDst_Multi to AdQueryTmp in AddNoteField. I call AdQueryTmp's before and calcfields methods, because frxDst_Multi does not have and it bind to adquerytmp

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible to say without your entire project and code  I suggest you create a new project containing **only** your frxDst_Multi and see if that correctly adds the Note field.  Try that and let me know, please..

Comment: Forget about frxDst_Multi, i just want to add more column to adquerytmp dataset at runtime.

Comment: What datatype is adquerytmp and did you try adding the Note field to that instead of frxDST_Multi **in a new project**?

Comment: AdQueryTmp is a TFDQuery. Okay, i am going to try in new project, you are probably right about big project.